# Using SshNet to Retrieve Folder List from Remote Server (SSH Interactive Client)

Tags: c#, ssh

I am trying to create an interactive SSH client session in C#. I am using the Renci.SshNet library to accomplish this. To get a proof of concept, I am only interested in connecting to the server, running the "ls" command, and retrieving the list of folders in the current directory.

I have been able to do this, however, I am getting (I believe) server domain's in my output as well as the file names. I have provided a picture at the bottom to show exactly what I am getting. I am not sure how to parse this....or am I even doing this the correct way? I have provided my code, a picture of the output, and what I wish the output to be.

```
// using....
using Renci.SshNet;

class Program
{
    private const String NEWLINE = "\n";
    private bool connected = false;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter hostname: ");
        String hostname = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter username: ");
        String username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter password: ");
        String password = Console.ReadLine();


        PasswordAuthenticationMethod pw = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password);
        ConnectionInfo ci = new ConnectionInfo(hostname, username, pw);
        SshClient ssh = new SshClient(ci);

        Console.Write("-Connecting...\n");
        ssh.Connect();

        IDictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint> termkvp = new Dictionary<Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes, uint>();
        termkvp.Add(Renci.SshNet.Common.TerminalModes.ECHO, 53);
        ShellStream shellStream = ssh.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024, termkvp);

        String line = null;
        String s = null;

        TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        while ((s = shellStream.ReadLine(timeout)) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        shellStream.Flush();

        while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
        {
            shellStream.Write(line);
            shellStream.Write(NEWLINE);

            while ((s = shellStream.ReadLine(timeout)) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            shellStream.Flush();
        }
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

(I have highlighted the portions that I am interested in getting)

[image]

Expected Output:

```
- Connecting...
Last login: Thu Apr 30 10:28:12 2015 from ...
ls     (user input)
    2015-03-18_0
    First_HFSS_Test
    First_Test
    ...
```

***EDIT***

When I use "dir" instead of "ls" I get the list of directory without the other information. I believe that the "ls" gives me the list with color information. Perhaps the information outside of the directory list is color data that has been translated???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [ANSI Escape Sequences](https://superuser.com/a/343776/392284), not only for encoding color instructions but sometimes used to specify cursor movement and draw regions.

You're getting interactive control codes back because [a terminal is not a shell](https://superuser.com/a/343776/392284). The shell considers the terminal on output decisions and your solution is probably in disabling aliases (actually, their parameters). [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/543147/392284) recommends using the full path to /bin/ls, quoting "ls" 'ls', backslashing \ls, or using command substitution: $(which ls).

Note also a comment above the linked answer: output redirection may be required so that commands don't truncate their output as they accommodate the window dimensions of the enclosing terminal. This is a little convoluted but should also get the job done.